# Two-dimensional subarrays (a smaller square out of a larger square)

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

Main question: you can easily get a subarray out of an array e.g. sub = a[2, 3]. But if you have a 2D array, how can you get a 2D subarray?

Practical example:
I'm trying to iterate over the 9 3x3 squares in a sudoku board, to check each 3x3 square for duplicate numbers.

If I have an array (board) of 9 arrays (rows), is there an easy way to get a 3x3 sub-2D-array of the board? Is there an easy way to go through all 9 of the 3x3 sub-2D-arrays?

Edit: sorry if the original wasn't clear, the main thing is the principle of getting a portion of a 2D array, the sudoku part is more of an application of the principle.

Comment: You really need to clarify your question (with an edit), both to stem (and possibly reverse) the downvotes and for the benefit of SO members that read it in future. You need to state your question clearly and precisely, which right now is implied and vague (hence the downvotes). I presume the question is, "given a Sudoku solution represented by an array `solution`, such that `solution[i][j]` is the entry (integer or string) in row `i+1`, column `j+1` (rows `1` to `9`, columns `1` to `9`), how do I determine if any of the nine 3x3 blocks contains a duplicate entry?

Comment: Yeah, @Mirror318 are you trying to verify that a puzzle has been solved or just trying to display a puzzle to be solved?

Comment: Hello! Hello! Anybody home?

Answer (score 2):

You could determine if a Sudoku solution is valid as follows. Checking the 3x3 blocks is simplified by using the method [Array#minor](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor).

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def valid?(soln)
  rows_invalid   = invalid_rows?(soln, "rows")
  cols_invalid   = invalid_rows?(soln.transpose, "columns")
  blocks_invalid = invalid_blocks?(soln)
  puts "Solution is valid" unless rows_invalid || cols_invalid || blocks_invalid
end

def invalid_rows?(soln, label)
  rows_with_dups = soln.each.with_index(1).select { |r,i| r.uniq.size < r.size }
  return false if rows_with_dups.empty?
  puts "Duplicates are in #{label}: #{ rows_with_dups.map(&:last).join(' ') }"
  return true
end

def invalid_blocks?(soln)
  m = Matrix[*soln]
  blocks_with_dups = [1,2,3].product([1,2,3]).select do |row,col|
    f_row, f_col = 3*(row-1), 3*(col-1)
    block = m.minor(f_row..(f_row+2), f_col..(f_col+2)).to_a.flatten
    block.uniq.size < block.size
  end
  return false if blocks_with_dups.empty? 
  puts "Duplicates are in blocks: #{ blocks_with_dups.map { |row,col|
    "(#{row}, #{col})" }.join(' ') }"
  return true
end
```

**Examples**

```
soln = [
  %w| 4 1 7 8 5 3 9 6 2 |,
  %w| 5 8 9 7 6 2 4 3 1 |,
  %w| 6 3 2 9 1 4 7 5 8 |,
  %w| 9 6 8 3 2 1 5 7 4 |,
  %w| 7 2 3 4 8 5 1 9 6 |,
  %w| 1 5 4 6 7 9 8 2 3 |,
  %w| 8 4 6 2 9 7 3 1 5 |,
  %w| 2 7 1 5 3 8 6 4 9 |,
  %w| 3 9 5 1 4 6 2 8 7 |,
]
  #=> [["4", "1", "7", "8", "5", "3", "9", "6", "2"],
  #    ["5", "8", "9", "7", "6", "2", "4", "3", "1"],
  #    ["6", "3", "2", "9", "1", "4", "7", "5", "8"],
  #    ["9", "6", "8", "3", "2", "1", "5", "7", "4"],
  #    ["7", "2", "3", "4", "8", "5", "1", "9", "6"],
  #    ["1", "5", "4", "6", "7", "9", "8", "2", "3"],
  #    ["8", "4", "6", "2", "9", "7", "3", "1", "5"],
  #    ["2", "7", "1", "5", "3", "8", "6", "4", "9"],
  #    ["3", "9", "5", "1", "4", "6", "2", "8", "7"]] 

valid?(soln)
  #=> "Solution is valid"
```

Now change two elements in `soln`:

```
soln[0][5] = "7"
soln[8][8] = "3"
soln.map { |row| row.join(' ') }
  #=> ["4 1 7 8 5 7 9 6 2",
  #    "5 8 9 7 6 2 4 3 1",
  #    "6 3 2 9 1 4 7 5 8",
  #    "9 6 8 3 2 1 5 7 4",
  #    "7 2 3 4 8 5 1 9 6",
  #    "1 5 4 6 7 9 8 2 3",
  #    "8 4 6 2 9 7 3 1 5",
  #    "2 7 1 5 3 8 6 4 9",
  #    "3 9 5 1 4 6 2 8 3"] 

valid?(soln)
  #=> Duplicates are in rows: 1 9
  #   Duplicates are in columns: 6 9
  #   Duplicates are in blocks: (1, 2) (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are having rows, which would make it complicated.

I recommend you to simply have an array `a` of length 81. Given the index `i` of an element, you can assume the beginning element of the row, column, or sub-square it belongs to, whose index is given as:

```
start_of_row        = (i / 9) * 9
start_of_column     = i % 9
start_of_sub_square = (i / 27) * 27 + (i % 9 / 3) * 3
```

Then, given a starting index `j`, you can iterate through the row, column, sub-square as follows:

```
row_indice        = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
column_indice     = [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72]
sub_square_indice = [0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20]
```

- iterate row:        `row_indice.each{|k| a[j + k]}`
- iterate column:     `column_indice.each{|k| a[j + k]}`
- iterate sub square: `sub_square_indice.each{|k| a[j + k]}`